# Fragment not appearing properly in two pane tablet mode

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to launch my fragment in the detail fragment & highlight the selected list item (code is there in **FragmentWCLine.java**) in two pane mode but for some reason it won't do so. Seems to work fine in single pane mode but when it comes to two pane mode it seems to ignore my code in the if(mTwoPane) section within **FragmentWCLine.java** and then decides to launch an activity rather than showing the fragment in the detail fragment & highlighting the selected list item. In **FragmentWCLine.java**, I'm not sure what to do with `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), mWC[position].fragmentClass));`. Also `FragmentLineChooserList newFragment = new FragmentLineChooserList();` needs to be changed to something else but I have no idea as to what that would be. How can I prevent the mTwoPane code from being ignored so that it does what it is supposed to along with the above that I want to achieve?

**WCLineActivity.java**

```
    public class WCLineActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        /**
         * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
         * device.
         */
        private boolean mTwoPane;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#66CCCC")));
            actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000099'>Hello World</font>"));

            if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
                mTwoPane = true;
            }

            FragmentWCLine newFragment = new FragmentWCLine();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }   
    }
```

**FragmentWCLine.java**

```
public class FragmentWCLine extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private class WC {
        private CharSequence station;
        private CharSequence zone;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;
        private Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass;

        public WC(int stationResId, int zoneResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass, Class<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment> fragmentClass) {
            this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.station = getResources().getString(stationResId);
            this.zone = getResources().getString(zoneResId);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return station.toString(); }
        public String getzone(){ return zone.toString(); }
    }

    private static WC[] mWC;

    /**
     * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
     * device.
     */
    public boolean mTwoPane;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc_line, container, false);


        if (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }else{
            mTwoPane = false;
        }

        // Instantiate the list of stations.
        mWC = new WC[]{
                new WC(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, WCAActivity.class, FragmentWCA.class),
                new WC(R.string.wat, R.string.zone_1, WCBActivity.class, FragmentWCB.class)
        };

        final ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_wc);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mWC));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);
                    Fragment newFragment;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            newFragment = new FragmentWCA();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            newFragment = new FragmentWCB();
                            break;
                        default:
                            newFragment = new FragmentWCA();
                            break;
                    }
                    WCLineActivity activity = (WCLineActivity) view.getContext();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                } else {
                    Intent intent;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WCAActivity.class);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WCBActivity.class);
                            break;
                        default:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WCAActivity.class);
                            break;
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

            public void setItemSelected(View view) {
                View rowView = view;
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66CCCC"));

                TextView tv0 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                tv0.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));

                TextView tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000099"));
            }

            public void setItemNormal() {
                for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View v = listView.getChildAt(i);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    TextView tv0 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station));
                    tv0.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    TextView tv1 = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone));
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B5B5B5"));
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView station;
            TextView zone;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        WC[] mWC;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, WC[] samples) {
            this.mWC = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mWC.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mWC[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.station = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_station);
                viewHolder.zone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_zone);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.station.setText(mWC[position].station);
            viewHolder.zone.setText(mWC[position].getzone());


            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**FragmentWC.java**

```
public class FragmentWC extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wc, container, false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

**fragment_wc.xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/detail_container">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Bank"
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_wc_line.xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentwcline">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_wc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml layout**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/master_container"
    android:name="com.apptacularapps.exitsexpertlondonlite.FragmentMainList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**activity_main.xml layout (sw600dp)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/master_container"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:id="@+id/detail_container"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Variable mTwoPane is declared private in FragmentWCLine.java. And that variable never changes. Simply set it to true as hack fix and it will be better. I believe I told this in previous posts but never got enough attention. Time to do something about it and making new posts about the same issue don't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you need to init boolean before fragment transaction:

```
if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }
FragmentWCLine newFragment = new FragmentWCLine();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
```

**Update:**

Also update click listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(mTwoPane){
                    setItemNormal();
                    View rowView = view;
                    setItemSelected(rowView);
                    Fragment newFragment;
                    switch (position){
                         case 0:
                            newFragment = new FragmentWCBank ();
                            break;
                         case 1:
                            newFragment = new FragmentWCWAT();
                            break;
                         default:
                            newFragment = new FragmentWCBank ();
                            break;
                    }
                    WCLineActivity activity = (WCLineActivity) view.getContext();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity .getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
                else{
                    Intent intent; 
                    switch (position){
                         case 0:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WCBankActivity.class);
                            break;
                         case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WCWATActivity.class);
                            break;
                         default:
                            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WCBankActivity.class);
                            break;
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80212/discussion-on-answer-by-anton-kovalyov-fragment-not-appearing-properly-in-two-pa).

Comment: Not the full solution, but your answer partially helped hence I'll give you the points anyway.